# Ultrasound cIeaning of PCBs with isopropyl alcohol

Tags: ultrasound, flux

I have tried to clean the flux remnants on a high-voltage PCB using isopropyl alcohol in ultrasound. The flux remnants were visible around the big SMD components such as transistors or in the creepage-distance cutouts. The main idea of the cleaning was to prepare the PCBs for potting.

The result was that after applying ultrasound for one hour the flux remnants are still there but seem broken up. The broken up flux remnants still stick to the PCB even though they can be manually removed relatively easily.

Is there any chance I could completely clean the PCB in ultrasound? Would increasing (how much?) the isopropyl alcohol temperature help?

Comment: Have you tried specialty flux cleaner solutions? What type of flux does you/your EMS use?

Comment: Isopropanol is a relatively mild solvent, you might look for something better or more appropriate to the particular flux you are using. I presume you're doing a rinse afterward with DI water to remove at least some of the dilute flux residue now covering the entire board (and wherever else it could migrate).

Comment: My first impulse for anything giving me trouble is to mix 100% sulfuric acid with potassium dichromate and apply. If still stubborn, then add RFNA liberally. The RFNA does tend to decap the ICs, too, but it gets the grime. ;) But @SpehroPefhany has the right of it. He should make an answer, I think. Also, when using isoprop, be sure to use 91% or better and to avoid anything with the word "rubbing" on it. Often that means oils are added. You do not want added oils. (I worked in chem labs as an assistant for a few years, with two atropine injectors at my belt in case of so-called `accidents`.)

Comment: The flux specs will have a recommendation for the solvent(s) to use for cleanup. If you try cleaning flux with isopropanol and then try proper flux remover, you will laugh at how easy the latter is.

Comment: can you add a pic of the PCB you are trying to clean, it is hard to visualize it

Comment: Use ethanol. It's much better at dissolving flux. Isopropyl works but requires much mechanical agitation. Isopropyl is often more used because it's cheaper and my understanding is that in technical grade isopropyl will have zero chance of oil residues in it, while technical grade ethanol is derived from petrochemicals (or something like that) so might contain trace amounts of oil. This is important for chemistry labs.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ethanol is avoided for commercial applications (e.g., in the pharmaceutical industry) because it typically has a high rate of excise duty imposed on it.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your ideas. I think the conclusion is IPA won't do the job, so I'll try and find out what flux was used and get an appropriate solvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance I could completely clean the PCB in ultrasound?

I would switch to a better solvent, if that is something that is tolerable and still PCB compatible. I usually recommend some of techsprays stuff but it wouldn't work well in a bath. IPA is a weak solvent:

> IPA isn’t a great cleaner. It has a Kb (Kauri-butanol) value of about
> 50, meaning it’s not strong enough to tackle the tougher-to-remove
> lead-free and no-clean flux residue commonly used today. It also isn’t
> very good at removing greasy or oily fingerprints.
> Source: https://www.microcare.com/en-US/Resources/Insights/June-2021/Stop-Using-IPA-to-Clean-Your-PCBs

Also make sure you are using 99% IPA and not something from the local store that has a lot of water in it.

So try and find something higher on the Kb scale that will work for your application.

> Would increasing (how much?) the isopropyl alcohol temperature help?

Yeah, but it will also cause your IPA to evaporate much faster as the boiling point is at ~80C, lower than water. Increasing it beyond 40C gets it into the air in a hurry.

Another thing would be to switch the flux, I really like chipquick 291 (no clean), and maybe they have something that would be easy to clean in a [water-soluable or rosin based](https://www.chipquik.com/store/index.php?cPath=300) that would work better with IPA

Answer (score 3):

Heat up a bit the IPA and gently brush the boards with an old toothbrush. That always worked for me. Don't use more aggressive solvents as they might damage plastic parts of some components (e.g. polyester caps dissolve in acetone). Also make sure that all parts are rated for ultrasonic washing. The datasheet of MEMS devices and OptoMOS/photovoltaic relays often forbid ultrasonic washing.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas, but I think I'll try and find out the flux that was used and get something more appropriate in the end. The IPA flammability has also scared me a bit.

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll find something more suitable as IPA is the industry standard. There are better solvents, but parts are only rated for IPA washing. Virtually all solvents are flammable. IPA is relatively safe, cheap, non-toxic. You might have better luck with other solvents but be extremely careful with them!